# Get product, with 0 quantity, by attribute (sku)

Tags: product, attributes, import, search

I'm importing products and I want to get product by its sku. This is the code:

```
$product = $this->productFactory->create();
$record = $product->loadByAttribute('sku', '1234');
```

It works but only with products that have quantity > 0 and product is enabled. How can I find product even if quantity == 0 or status is disabled?

Answer (score 0):

Try using Resource collection,

```
 $productCollection = $obj->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection');
 /** Apply filters here */
$collection = $productCollection->addAttributeToSelect('*')
            ->addAttributeToFilter('sku', $sku);
 foreach ($collection as $product){
 echo "<pre>";
 print_r($product->getData());
}
```

This will give you the product details irrespective of status or qty value

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this below code :

```
$collection = $this->_productFactory->create();
        $collection->setFlag('has_stock_status_filter', true);
        $collection = $collection->addAttributeToFilter('sku', ['eq' => '1234'])->addAttributeToSelect(['name', 'sku'])
            ->addAttributeToSort('created_at', 'DESC')
            ->joinField('qty',
                'cataloginventory_stock_item',
                'qty',
                'product_id=entity_id',
                '{{table}}.stock_id=1',
                'left'
            )->joinTable('cataloginventory_stock_item', 'product_id=entity_id', ['stock_status' => 'is_in_stock'])
            ->addAttributeToSelect('stock_status')
            ->addFieldToFilter('stock_status', ['eq' => 0])
            ->load();
```